# Rounding to whole number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have here an HTML code which compute for the charges of payment. How can I round of the value in whole number? I have tried `Math.round()` but still, it didn't work. Is there a way also to replace the `NaN` value to zero?

```
<div class="collapse" id="pera-padala">
  <div class="card card-body">
        <div class="form-element">
        <span>B. Input ang amount na ipapadala  </span>
        <input name="entry.1812134286" id="padala-pera"  type="number"  required="">
      </div>
      <br>
       <div class="form-element">
              <span>C. Total Babayaran: <span id="padala-result"></span>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $('#padala-pera').keyup(function(){
           if (jQuery('#padala-pera').val() <= 1000) {
   jQuery('#padala-result').text("₱".concat(parseFloat($('#padala-pera').val())+30));
}
    else if (jQuery('#padala-pera').val() > 1000) {
   jQuery('#padala-result').text("₱".concat(parseFloat($('#padala-pera').val())+(parseFloat(jQuery('#padala-pera').val())*.03)));
}
  });
  </script>
```

Here is my jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/sodium05/u3qdyh51/15/

Comment: Your code should be posted **here**. Stack Overflow has facilities that allow for runnable code samples right here on this site.

Comment: of course `Math.round()` works. You just aren't using it.

Comment: How did you try and use round? Show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to round to whole number you have three options.

- Round with [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)
- Round down with [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)
- Round up with [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

Just ensure that you are providing numberic inputs to these functions.

Also to handle no input, if no inout is present use '0' as input value.

```js
$('#padala-pera').keyup(function () {
  let inputVal = $('#padala-pera').val();
  inputVal = inputVal ? inputVal : '0';
  if (inputVal <= 1000) {
    $('#padala-result').text("₱".concat(Math.round(parseFloat(inputVal) + 30)));
    $('#padala-result-up').text("₱".concat(Math.ceil(parseFloat(inputVal) + 30)));
    $('#padala-result-down').text("₱".concat(Math.floor(parseFloat(inputVal) + 30)));
  }
  else if (inputVal > 1000) {
    $('#padala-result').text("₱".concat(Math.round(parseFloat(inputVal) + (parseFloat(inputVal) * .03))));
    $('#padala-result-up').text("₱".concat(Math.ceil(parseFloat(inputVal) + (parseFloat(inputVal) * .03))));
    $('#padala-result-down').text("₱".concat(Math.floor(parseFloat(inputVal) + (parseFloat(inputVal) * .03))));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="collapse" id="pera-padala">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <div class="form-element">
      <span>B. Input ang amount na ipapadala </span>
      <input name="entry.1812134286" id="padala-pera" type="number" required="">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-element">
      <span>C. Total Babayaran: Rounding <span id="padala-result"></span>
      <br>
      <span>C. Total Babayaran: Rounding Up<span id="padala-result-up"></span>
      <br>
      <span>C. Total Babayaran: Rounding Down<span id="padala-result-down"></span>

      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code alot. Math.round() works fine but you need to make sure you're converting your strings into numbers (any value derived from an HTML element is a string even if it comes from a Number element). Your code had parseInt in some places but not in the conditionals. I like to use the shorthand `+` prefix for str -> num conversions

```js
$('#padala-pera').keyup(function() {
  let n = +$(this).val()
  if (n <= 1000) n += 30
  else n += n * .03;
  $('#padala-result').text(`₱${Math.round(n)}`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse" id="pera-padala">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <div class="form-element">
      <span>B. Input ang amount na ipapadala  </span>
      <input name="entry.1812134286" id="padala-pera" type="number" required="">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-element">
      <span>C. Total Babayaran: 
      <span id="padala-result"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```